# Squeeze Theorem to solve $\lim_{x\to1} \sin\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can the limit  $$\lim_{x\to1^+} \sin\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{{x^2-1}}$$ be evaluated?
My attempt employed the squeeze theorem and obtained
$$\frac{\sqrt{(-1+1)}}{x^2-1} \lt  \sin\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{{x^2-1}}\lt  \frac{\sqrt{(1+1)}}{x^2-1} $$
and from there conclued that $$\lim_{x\to1^+} \sin\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{{x^2-1}} = \infty$$

But I've never seen it used like this (probably because it can't be...) Any thoughts?

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: The sine function is bounded by $1$;  so, the limit, if it existed, would need to be likewise.  That said, the limit does not exist, but rather fluctuates between $-1$ and $1$ as $x\to 1^+$